# Laravel Eloquent relationship between 3 tables

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am doing a school project on logistics and am using laravel for it. I have a delivery table and returns table which has all the deliveries inside and returns inside respectively. The delivery and returns table has a type which is Normal Delivery or Return Delivery and has a address id which is mapped to the address table. Both the delivery and return table has a tracking Id which is the same

If its a Normal delivery, i have to refer to the customer table to get the customer details, if its a Return Delivery, i have to refer to the driver table to get the driver details.

My delivery model as below

```
class Delivery extends Eloquent {
    public function address()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Address','id', 'address_id');
    }

    public function customer()
    {
       return $this->hasOne('Customer', 'id', 'customer_id');
    }   

    public function driver()
    {
         return $this->hasOne('Driver', 'id', 'driver_id');
    } 

    public function return()
    {
         return $this->hasOne('Return', 'id', 'delivery_id');
    }
}
```

My Return model as below

```
 class Return extends Eloquent {

    public function address()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Address','id', 'address_id');
    }

    public function customer()
    {
       return $this->hasOne('Customer', 'id', 'customer_id');
    }   

    public function driver()
    {
         return $this->hasOne('Driver', 'id', 'driver_id');
    } 

      public function delivery()
    {
         return $this->hasOne('Delivery', 'id', 'return_id');
    }
}
```

My Customer model as below

```
class Customer extends Eloquent {

   public function addresses()
   {
         return $this->hasMany('Address', 'client_id', 'client_id');
   }


    public function delivery()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Delivery', 'customer_id', 'id');
    }
```

My Driver model as below

```
class Driver extends Eloquent {

    public function addresses()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Address', 'client_id', 'client_id');
    }

    public function delivery()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Delivery', 'driver_id', 'id');
    }
```

My Address model as below

```
class Address extends Eloquent {

    public function customer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Customer', 'client_id', 'client_id');      
    }

    public function driver()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Driver', 'client_id', 'client_id');        
    }

    public function return()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Return', 'address_id', 'id');
    }

    public function delivery()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Delivery', 'address_id', 'id');
    }
```

So right now, given a tracking id, I need to grab all the deliveries and return rows, along with the correct address. Currently I am doing it as below for deliveries

```
$deliveries = Delivery::select(array('*', DB::raw('COUNT(id) as count')))->with('address','address.customer','customer')->whereIn('tracking_id', $tracking_id)
```

and for returns

```
$returns= Return::select(array('*', DB::raw('COUNT(id) as count')))->with('address','address.driver','customer')->whereIn('tracking_id', $tracking_id)
```

When I combine these two together, I have to check whether it is a delivery or return before I can access the address.customer for the delivery and address.driver for the return. Is there any way to resolve this that when I combine these two sets of results togther, i can still access a address.contact for example which returns me the details for that address?

Comment: I would do away with the `Returns` table and model and make the `Delivery` table/model polymorphic in which you would just add a column for the foreign key to either the `Customer` or `Driver` tables and a column for telling Laravel which model it belongs to, `Customer` or `Driver`.

Comment: You seem to have made this very complicated. You only really need a single 'Delivery' model, with a switch for Return or Initial delivery, then have the address model/table a polymorphic relation.

Comment: @edelweiss even i have the same problem joining 3 tables through eloquent, Have you got solution for this, can u share if possible.